# My screensaver does not turn on - what could be preventing it?

Tags: windows-7, screensaver, passwords, physical-security

My screensaver will not turn on - despite everything set properly, it sometimes never activates. This is a problem, as I need screensaver password protection if I step away from the computer for an hour or so.

The only thing I can think of is that my mouse or keyboard driver is somehow keeping it active by somehow sending phantom keystrokes to the computer to top the screensaver activating.

I have an external USB Kensington keyboard, an external HP mouse, and my laptop is a Toshiba with Win7.

Is there any way to diagnose and fix this problem, or any utilities that could automatically password protect my computer from unauthorized use if I step away for a few minutes?

Comment: I think this is a superuser type question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need physical security you should lock your workstation the moment you leave and not five minutes after you left.

So you might just press <kbd>Windows</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> to lock the workstation immediately.

Comment: Sure - but sometimes I forget, then the computer is unlocked all weekend. I'd rather have my screensaver working, so at least it won't be unlocked all weekend, available to the cleaners on Sunday, etc.

Comment: @Gravitas you could also just turn it off over the weekend...

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: There are times that I may be required to access my work computer from home over the weekend, so turning it off for me is not an option.